# Are there any definitive kill/death counts from Star Trek that includes all catastrophic events?

Tags: star-trek

Star Wars has a kill count wiki, and a number of characters listed there have numbers reaching far into the trillions (although I'm not sure if there are even that many people available to kill). Does Star Trek have a similar kill/death count that includes all the battles/catastrophes from all the shows? Death counts have been listed for certain major battles such as Wolf 359 or the Sector of 001, but what about in large-scale wars, such as the Dominion War? I'm talking about everyone, Federation and non-Federation alike, but I would want the answer to exclude any alternate universes and alternate timelines, if possible.

Comment: @JiminyCricket. No, not alternate timelines. Sorry about that. I'll edit my question to clarify.

Comment: I'd sure like to know how many individuals Nagilum and Armus have snuffed out.

Comment: Does the Borg Collective count as a single character?

Comment: @GeoffAtkins It would count as one group.